# Scraping table from website: Cannot address correct table

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, html-table

I am a Python newbie and just started to learn it, and have the following problem: I want to scrape the portfolio data from a website ( https://www.wikifolio.com/de/de/w/wffalkinve ; scroll down, click on "Portfolio"); but I cannot address the right tr class "c-portfolio", but always end with values for the first table on the right "Erstemission 20.09.2019" etc.

I have tried over 15 approaches with web tutorials and questions/answers on reddit/stackoverflow, but cant solve it, i guess its quite special on this website. Down there is my most advanced code.

I would be so thankful for any advices! :)

Best,
Julian

```
import requests, six
import lxml.html as lh
from itertools import cycle, islice
from matplotlib import colors
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

url='https://www.wikifolio.com/de/de/w/wffalkinve'

#Create a handle, page, to handle the contents of the website
page = requests.get(url)

#Store the contents of the website under doc
doc = lh.fromstring(page.content)

#Parse data that are stored between <tr>..</tr> of the site's HTML code
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//tbody')

#Check the length of the first 12 rows
[len(T) for T in tr_elements[:12]]
```

gives Output of [5, 4]

```
#Create empty list
col=[]
i=0

#For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[0]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()
    print('%d: %s' % (i,name))
    col.append((name,[]))
```

Other attempts:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://www.wikifolio.com/de/de/w/wffalkinve'
html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)



soup.find_all('tr')

# Print the first 10 rows for sanity check
rows = soup.find_all('tr')
print(rows[:10])

for row in rows:
    row_td = row.find_all('td')
print(row_td)
type(row_td)


str_cells = str(row_td)
cleantext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text()
print(cleantext)

import re

list_rows = []
for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    str_cells = str(cells)
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    clean2 = (re.sub(clean, '',str_cells))
    list_rows.append(clean2)
print(clean2)
type(clean2)

df = pd.DataFrame(list_rows)
df.head(10)

df1 = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
df1.head(10)
```

I thought this one would be the solution, but it delivers no outpout at all

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
a = requests.get("https://www.wikifolio.com/de/de/w/wffalkinve")
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text, 'lxml')
# searching for the rows directly
rows = soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'c-portfolio'})
print(rows[:100])
```

Edit: To make it easier to find the respective table: the tr class c-portfolio

https://ibb.co/nckVC1h

Comment: If the content which you are trying to scrape is dependent on javascript to load, then Pandas, BS solutions will not work. i would suggest to use selenium - chrome headless based solution.

Comment: I´ll try - right now i have no clue what selenium is :D Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you or anyone else knows some resources that try scraping a table with selenium? I cant find appropriate solutions, but might search wrong

Comment: take a look at the related answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52448137/python-selenium-scrape-the-whole-table